# Windows Server 2008R2 DNS local IP's

Tags: active-directory, domain-name, internal-dns

I have a Windows Server 2008R2 server running as our domain controller and DNS server. We have a number of local IP addresses that users access quite a few times a day. At the moment they have to remember that '192.168.1.1' is the intranet and '192.168.1.2' is an internal management application etc.

I was wondering, as all the workstations are using our DNS server, which points to OpenDNS using a forwarder, would it be possible to set the DNS server to divert all requests for 'http://intranet.local' (as an example) to '192.168.1.1'?

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't require manipulation of all the workstations' host files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just setup a zone and add the relevant records to it.

Comment: Can it work in the reverse? For instance, if I wanted to divert all requests for Facebook.com to an internal page?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.